# How to remove *all* call history in Windows Phone 8.1?

Tags: 8.1, calls

In the original Windows Phone, open the "Phone" app, then press "...", there is an option "Delete all history". However, in Windows Phone 8.1, it's gone! I can only delete individual calls by holding on a call, wait for the popup menu, then select "Delete".

How can I remove all call history in Windows Phone 8.1?

Answer (score 2):

This feature is somewhat "hidden", so I will post it here:

1. Open Phone app.
2. Tap "...", then tap "select calls".
3. On this screen, tap "..." again. (this is difficult to find!)
4. Tap "select all".
5. Tap the trash icon.

Comment: The Pivot UI (the three dots at the bottom of the screen) is a part of WP8.1 and it will hold all the menu options except some quick actions. It was well integrated into all the apps of the OS and not something unique to call history. Messaging apps, whatsapp, people and other apps had this option(select all) in the same place. Just out of curiosity, was it that much difficult?

Comment: @KolappanNathan the problem is Microsoft moved the item from its original place. This is unexpected. The new location requires 3 extra taps. Also, the "..." UI is usually used when the bottom bar is already occupied by 4 icons. In this case, there is only one. They could have easily put the "select all" icon next to the "trash" icon, but not hide it under the menu.